# Is it possible to change the location of Service Fabric Binaries on Azure Cluster

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Is it possible to change the location of Service Fabric on a Azure-Hosted cluster ?

```
"publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric",
"settings": {
    "clusterEndpoint": "[reference(parameters('clusterName')).clusterEndpoint]",
    "nodeTypeRef": "[parameters('vmNodeType0Name')]",
    "dataPath": "D:\\\\SvcFab",
    "durabilityLevel": "Silver",
    "certificate": {
        "thumbprint": "[parameters('certificateThumbprint')]",
        "x509StoreName": "[parameters('certificateStoreValue')]"
    },
    "certificateSecondary": {
        "thumbprint": "[parameters('secondaryCertificateThumbprint')]",
        "x509StoreName": "[parameters('certificateStoreValue')]"
    }
},
```

If possible we would like to move from temporary disk D: into a datadisk like F:

Since the disk won't be initialised at the point of the cluster  creation could I change this after the install and re-run the ARM deployment ?

Comment: did you manage to change this? Actually I'd like to change location where statefull services/reliable collections kept their data but documentation doesn't mention anything like that.